# Development differences between Force.com User License and Force.com Admin license?

Tags: licenses

I'm led to believe that a user with the Force.com Admin license can develop in Apex, VF, make WF Rules and Triggers, etc.

What about a Force.com User License? Can somebody outline these inclusions and exclusions for me? I can't find these specifications in any documentation. If my question can be answered with some pre-existing documentation, feel free to send the link my way! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean Profiles? Salesforce doesn't have different Licenses for 'Admin' and 'non-Admin' users, they are all usually just Salesforce License users (Standard License.)

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_understanding_license_types.htm&language=en_US

Through profiles you should be able to grant any of your users access to edit Apex, VF, Workflow, etc. You will need to grant them access to 'Customize Application'.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=wf_approval_settings.htm

You do not want to give that to all users - but you could give it to a subset of users who you want to give access to edit the functionality of the application.